# Justification for use of custom Langs

Tags: discussion

## Justification of user-created languages to gain an advantage in the future

On my question, [Rolling the Dice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/rolling-the-dice/), I received [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/rolling-the-dice/66627#66627) answer.

In it [@zocky](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48095/zocky) asked about the justification of using ultra-short languages specifically designed for code golf to win challenges.

On my question wasn't really the right place to post the question, but seeing as how he has a point, I am re-asking it on meta.

My question is this:

### Why should we allow people to make their own languages to solve problems?

I know we have rules like languages have to be pre-existing, have an interpreter, etc. but what justifies the use of languages built to be ultra-short?  Like why should we not be constrained to languages that are used elsewhere?

Comment: IIRC, that language violates a standard loophole.

Comment: That particular language is particularly invalid. It's entirely based on [this standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1062/42545): loading data from an external source to solve the challenge. Plus, it won't ever be valid except when one challenge is an exact duplicate of an existing one, since it nearly always requires changes to made to the interpreter after the challenge is posted.

Comment: They don't need justification. Languages are allowed unless they specifically aren't. That one specifically isn't because any working interpreter would have to be updated after the question is posted.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I know.  That one in particular is *very* invalid, but the point he makes is not.

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes, I informed zocky of that.

Comment: Seems like a variation of MetaGolfScript, which is also [forbidden](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5076/42963)

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I know, but I didn't say golfing langs are disallowed. (in my post)

Comment: @RikerW I feel like I'm misunderstanding the question, then. You asked why languages for code golfing are allowed, and the reason is "we haven't banned them".

Comment: I am not meaning to say that golfing langs should be disallowed, I mean to collect reasons why you are allowed to write your own language.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand a little bit better. You're not asking "what rule allows this" so much as you are "what are the reasons this decision was made", right?

Comment: YES!!!!  I am thinking something like "If they take the time and do the work to create a language, they can use it."

Comment: In either case I think the answer is going to be very similar ("we allow languages by default and there's no reason to ban you from writing your own") but I see where you're coming from now.

Comment: This topic, and topics directly related, have been discussed many times before. Relevant posts include http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/286/42963 ... http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6983/42963 ... http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/630/42963 ... http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/185/42963

Comment: Why do they need to be "justified"? That's like saying "Okay, nobody's allowed to use C# here until we figure out a good reason to allow it."

Comment: Edited my question, reread please.  "Justify" was a bad word choice.  I mean to ask why custom languages can be created to win challenges.

Comment: ... well, now the answer is simply: Why not?

Comment: Did a mod delete @zocky's answer, or did he?

Comment: @Doorknob冰 because it would be unfair to more verbose langs. 
But the counter argument would be pick a new lang.
I mean that what justifies making a language just to win a challenge

Comment: "Oh, no, Ruby is shorter than Java! Well, we better ban Ruby."

Comment: Languages/interpreters are generally only restricted to needing to exist before the challenge is posted. *Creating* a new language after a challenge is posted (or adding specific functionality to an existing language) is generally frowned upon unless the challenge explicitly says otherwise. No "justification" needed.

Comment: Where do you draw the line? APL and its descendants (J, K, etc) are almost as short as dedicated golfing languages, and sometimes shorter when it comes to mathematical array-processing. These languages were not designed for code golf ... they just happen to be incredibly terse. And they *are* used professionally. If we start disallowing "golfing languages" (whatever that means... someone called Hexagony a golfing language...), then these will take over the leaderboards, and people will complain about *them* instead.

Answer (score 10):

> Why should we allow people to make their own languages to solve problems?

Why not?

Comment: Perhaps qualify with "as long as no standard loopholes are violated in the process"?

Answer (score 4):

## A language is a language

There's nothing that makes one language better than another, except for the sort of things in the Standard Loopholes.

> Why should we allow people to make their own languages to solve problems?

Because once someone's made a language, it's just as good as any other. PPCG doesn't discriminate based on outside popularity, and I think that's a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

## Every language has its first users

APL seemed quite esoteric to most people. It has some weird symbols like ⍋ for sorting, ⍉ for transpose, ⍣ for repetition, ⌊ and ⌈ for rounding down and up. The last two also had some weird names like floor and ceiling... weird only if they weren't accepted by more people and didn't become the standard mathematical symbols nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

## Because if people do the work and make a language, they can use it.

I thought for a bit and decided on this.  If people take the time and effort to make their own language, they can use it.

Comment: -1. People should also be able to use golfing languages that others have designed; there's no special privilege to the language designer.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I don't think that's what he is insinuating at all.